# PHP Request failed on SSL

Tags: php, curl, httprequest

Hello I would like to get some data from a url. I already tried to make a request through the console, postman, browset - all of them worked correctly. But if I make a request using php (guzzle, symfony http client) it fails on SSL. Does anybody know how to get response from [this](https://www.skroutz.gr/c/900/fakoi-epafhs.json) url by curl? Thanks!

Comment: where is the code that failed? Can you add all relevant code that you need help with to your question or risk the question being closed.

Comment: Please describe your problem properly

Comment: Well i found 3 websites where you can make a request. First two where it does not work are here: https://reqbin.com/, https://www.apirequest.io/ and third where it works is here https://apitester.com/. I might have some similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code ( That's worked for me ):

```
<?php

function curl( $url, $data = array(), $headers = array(), $ssl_required = false ) {

 $handle = curl_init( $url );

 curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

 // Set post data if exist
 if ( !empty( $data ) ) {

   curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_POST, true );
   curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );

 }

 // Set custom headers if exist
 if ( count( $headers ) )
   curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

 // If url was ssl, need to true
 if ( $ssl_required )
   curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

 $output = curl_exec( $handle );

 curl_close( $handle );

 return $output;

}

echo curl("https://www.skroutz.gr/c/900/fakoi-epafhs.json");
```

Comment: Well it is funny because 5 times in row i did not work. Then i worked for 2 times and now it does not work again. It returns empty string.

Comment: @Jack I've tested for about 10 times and there isn't any problem to get data. could you tell me where you send this request? Maybe your connection is not reliable...